# Windows 10 has removed the GRUB menu

Tags: linux, windows-7, ubuntu, boot, grub

I have installed Ubuntu alongside Windows 10 in dual boot. Windows 10 was already installed, and I manually installed Ubuntu from a bootable USB. Dual boot was working properly and I was able to switch between the two operating systems with ease by using the GRUB menu at boot time. For some reason, I wanted to check the boot sequence in the BIOS. I was initially in Windows 10, then I restarted the machine and connected to the BIOS. Interestingly, I did not even see Ubuntu in the boot sequence. Other than that, the boot sequence was as I expected, so I did not make any changes. When I exited the BIOS and selected `exit and save changes`, even though I did not make any changes as far as I know. In hindsight, I should have selected `exit and discard changes`. As the machine finished restarting, it automatically booted into Windows 10 and did not display the GRUB menu. GRUB is completely gone as far as I can tell. The hard drive partition containing Ubuntu still exists, but I have no way of booting into it. I have tried the boot repair by following these steps:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

It was unsuccessful. The fists time that I went through the process, it indicated that I needed to disable secure boot. So, I went back to the BIOS and did that. I tried the boot repair again and it was still unsuccessful. I have read that this is a fairly common problem where Windows 10 will trash GRUB. Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you boot Ubuntu from UEFI boot menu (not UEFI settings)? Post link to summary report from Boot-Repair as it suggests, so we can see details. But Windows updates will reset Windows to first in boot order, grub major updates do the same thing & change boot order to Ubuntu/grub as first. And Windows may do an UEFI/BIOS update and reset UEFI to defaults. I keep a list of changes as my system requires several UEFI setting changes to work or work well. Some newer systems now can do an UEFI update from Ubuntu and then same issue on UEFI settings.

Comment: Oddly enough, Ubuntu does not appear in the UEFI boot menu.

Comment: I did an advanced restart in Windows and chose the option to boot from USB or CD when prompted. There were several options to choose from. For some reason, Linpus Lite was listed as one of the options. I selected it and the computer restarted. At boot time, the GRUB menu appeared and I was able to boot into Ubuntu. It seems very strange that it would be recognized as Linpus Lite...

Comment: If you had previously installed Linpus Lite, the UEFI menu remembers old entries. If you can boot into your Ubuntu, reinstall grub. You may want to check that fstab has correct ESP as that is what grub will use. UEFI uses partUUID to know which partition is ESP. See: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1198221/cloning-ssd-also-cloned-boot-options/1198228#1198228 & https://askubuntu.com/questions/1195682/boot-problem-in-uefi-multiboot-system-with-separate-drives-in-ubuntu-18-04 Once you know Ubuntu boots corectly you can remove Linpus UEFI entry.